# What's the correct way to use deliveryTime?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

```
    self.mirror_service.timeline().insert(
        body={
            'text': '123 456',
            'notification': {
                'deliveryTime': rfc3339.timestamp_from_tf(timestamp_after_duration),
                'level': 'DEFAULT'
            },
        }
    ).execute()
```

The formatted timestamp looks like this: `2013-06-16T02:47:33-00:00` which seems to be correct but I'm getting a bad request/400. Is there an example of using this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2013-06-16T15:46:51.561Z

Is an example of a timestamp string that the mirror API likes.

If I just remove the trailing Z I start getting a 400.  I also see you have a hyphen in your timestamp string that should probably be removed.

Note that even if you get a 200, you might not get the behavior you expect.  There is an open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=103) in the tracker about deliveryTime.

Here is my entire notification JSON that works:

```
  "notification": {
    "level": "DEFAULT",
    "deliveryTime": "2013-06-16T15:46:51.561Z"
  }
```

Comment: What does do the .561 in the Z mean? Sub second prescision?

Comment: Yes.  I tested and if you omit it, you will get a 400, but if you just put .000 there you get a 200 response.